# spark retrieving more than 20 records

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a file called students.json that looks like this:

```
{"uid":1,"name":"Michael","sid":1}
{"uid":2,"name":"Andy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":3,"name":"Jsaxsustin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":4,"name":"Andasxsay", "age":30,"sid":2}
{"uid":5,"name":"Jusewedtin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":6,"name":"Anwereddy", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":7,"name":"Justdwedwein", "age":19,"sid":2}
{"uid":8,"name":"Andwedewy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":9,"name":"Justidedwn", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":10,"name":"Anddwdey", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":11,"name":"Michael","sid":1}
{"uid":12,"name":"Andy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":13,"name":"Jsaxsustin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":14,"name":"Andasxsay", "age":30,"sid":2}
{"uid":15,"name":"Jusewedtin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":16,"name":"Anwereddy", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":17,"name":"Justdwedwein", "age":19,"sid":2}
{"uid":18,"name":"Andwe2fr3fdewy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":19,"name":"Justide4y45y54dwn", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":20,"name":"Anddwd45y45yey", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":21,"name":"Justdw45y45yedin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":22,"name":"An45y45ydy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":23,"name":"Jsaxsus4y54ytin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":24,"name":"Andas45y4y5xsay", "age":30,"sid":2}
{"uid":25,"name":"Jusewe4y5dtin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":26,"name":"Anwere45y45yddy", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":27,"name":"Justdwe4y4y5dwein", "age":19,"sid":2}
{"uid":28,"name":"Andwede45ywy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":29,"name":"Justided45y45wn", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":30,"name":"Anddwde4t4y", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":31,"name":"Mich4y554ael","sid":1}
{"uid":32,"name":"An45ydy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":33,"name":"Jsaxsudfsstin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":34,"name":"Andasxssdfdsay", "age":30,"sid":2}
{"uid":35,"name":"Jusewedtsdfdsin", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":36,"name":"Anweredsfdsdy", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":37,"name":"Justdwedfsdwein", "age":19,"sid":2}
{"uid":38,"name":"Andwedewy", "age":30,"sid":1}
{"uid":39,"name":"Jdsfdsfustidedwn", "age":19,"sid":1}
{"uid":40,"name":"Ansdfdsey", "age":30,"sid":3}
{"uid":41,"name":"Jussdsdtdwedin", "age":19,"sid":1}
```

then I am using sparks to import the data and do an sql query on it using sqlContext. To retrieve the information I am using the follwing scala code (almost taken out of a spark example on scala):

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
import sqlContext.implicits._
val students = sqlContext.read.json("../myTests/students.json");
students.registerTempTable("students");
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students").show;
```

This instead of returning all items of the list it only return 20 records(the first 20 records)...
If on the last line instead of

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students").show;
```

I put

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students where uid>10").show;
```

it gives me 20 records from 10 to 30. 
In short I want to see more than 20 records, how can I do that? is it possible? I have looked in the documentation and have not read anything about this.... I know that it might be a bit silly but I am doing some tests before I get into anything more serious... I downloaded the spark and I am running it as an standalone just to see the scala...

my spark initialization shows this(only Error, I changed the config so that it would not show me info)

```
15/07/17 11:37:55 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoo
p binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Ha
doop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Group
s.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupI
nformation.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(Use
rGroupInformation.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(
UserGroupInformation.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGrou
pInformation.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGr
oupInformation.java:621)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils
.scala:2162)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils
.scala:2162)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2162)
        at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.<init>(SparkIMain.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter.<init>(SparkIL
oop.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createInterpreter(SparkILoop.scala:2
17)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:949)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark
ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClass
Loader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$pr
ocess(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub
mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:16
9)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.4.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_21)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> studentsstudentsstudentsstudents
```

Thanks

Comment: may I ask "where" do you "see/get" your output? output of your IDE? shell?

Comment: I am using the spark-shell

Comment: did this happen too if you try to "import" a simple .txt file instead of a .json?

Comment: I created a csv file and imported as a text file, then using a class created the temporal table and did the query on it and have the same 20 lines issue

Comment: could you please post your spark context initialization? could it be something connected to partitions or number of cores?

Comment: all I am running as a test is a standalone version of spark.... just downloaded the tar, untar it and run spark shell, I am just testing to see the scala language and seeing how it behaves... I have not install it on clusters or anything like that... However this is the initialization:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students") returns a DataFrame instance, refer to [DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). To retrieve different # of rows, you can call ".take(n)":

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students where uid>10").take(30).foreach(println)
```

Comment: not exactly the way I want to see the data but I guess it works, Thanks :-)

Comment: actually thanks to your comment I found what I wanted. I first save the count into a variable then pass it into the show command like this:
var count = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students").count().toInt();
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students").show(count);

Comment: @user1342645 - Note, if you have a large dataset (e.g., billions of rows, which is really what spark is intended for) even count can be an expensive operation, especially on a CSV file.  If you have a rough idea of how many rows your result will be, you can always just set count to something larger.  For example, for your  30 row result, show(10000) will give you the same result as show(30).  You don't need to know the precise count up front, just the maximum number of rows you want to see on screen.

Answer (score 6):

Lets say you want to see 100 rows, you could also use,

```
df.show(100)

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM students where uid>10").show(100)
```

link to the [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html)

Comment: Give some bigger number than existence.